# Merge Results from Two GET Requests into Single Iterable Object in Angular 8/ Typescript with forkJoin

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular8

I'm using a forkJoin to get results from two separate endpoints. I can iterate on results[0] and results[1] however, I cannot go a level down to the values. IE: I cannot do results[0].amiiboId it always returns undefined, even though when I look at the full object of results[0] I can see it has an amiiboId (and all other fields).

I am assigning results[0] to a property called amiiboCollection but I need to use fields from both results[0] and results[1] in my template. Is there a way to merge these two objects so that my 2nd response is a child of the first response? Example below:

```
let amiibo = this.amiiboService.getAllAmiibo();
    let collection = this.amiiboService.getCollection(this.userId);

    forkJoin([amiibo, collection]).subscribe(results => {
      // results[0] is amiibo
      // results[1] is collection
      (results[0] as any).collection = results[1];
      this.amiiboCollection = results[0];


      console.log(this.amiiboCollection);
    });
```

### The first end point will return:

```
[
{
    "amiiboId": 1,
    "series": {
        "seriesId": 1,
        "seriesName": "Super Smash Bros. series "
    },
    "name": "Mario",
    "imageUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/amiibo/9L3Onnk5QzEp9CY8FtCKu65GjBbwr05O.png",
    "naReleaseDate": "2014-11-21",
    "jpReleaseDate": null,
    "euReleaseDate": null,
    "auReleaseDate": null
},
{
    "amiiboId": 2,
    "series": {
        "seriesId": 1,
        "seriesName": "Super Smash Bros. series "
    },
    "name": "Donkey Kong ",
    "imageUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/amiibo/AO2t6rdJrmc6bn8ADwGC0v_IR1Y8Zju-.png",
    "naReleaseDate": "2014-11-21",
    "jpReleaseDate": null,
    "euReleaseDate": null,
    "auReleaseDate": null
}
]
```

### And the second end point will return:

```
{
    "collectionId": 55,
    "amiiboId": 1,
    "userId": 12,
    "collected": "Y",
    "quantity": null,
    "collectedInBox": null,
    "collectedInBoxQuantity": null,
    "favorited": null,
    "wishlisted": null,
    "addDate": "2020-01-09T23:17:45.734+0000",
    "modDate": "2020-01-09T23:17:45.735+0000"
},
{
    "collectionId": 59,
    "amiiboId": 2,
    "userId": 12,
    "collected": "N",
    "quantity": null,
    "collectedInBox": null,
    "collectedInBoxQuantity": null,
    "favorited": null,
    "wishlisted": null,
    "addDate": "2020-01-11T19:09:36.177+0000",
    "modDate": "2020-01-11T19:09:36.177+0000"
},
```

### I would like to have a combined object like this:

```
[
    {
    "amiiboId": 1,
    "series": {
        "seriesId": 1,
        "seriesName": "Super Smash Bros. series "
    },
    "name": "Mario",
    "imageUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/amiibo/9L3Onnk5QzEp9CY8FtCKu65GjBbwr05O.png",
    "naReleaseDate": "2014-11-21",
    "jpReleaseDate": null,
    "euReleaseDate": null,
    "auReleaseDate": null,
    "collection": {
        "collectionId": 55,
    "amiiboId": 1,
    "userId": 12,
    "collected": "Y",
    "quantity": null,
    "collectedInBox": null,
    "collectedInBoxQuantity": null,
    "favorited": null,
    "wishlisted": null,
    "addDate": "2020-01-09T23:17:45.734+0000",
    "modDate": "2020-01-09T23:17:45.735+0000"
    },
    },
    ]
```

**I am also open to other ways to do this, or if there is a "right way" to handle this, I would love to learn more about that.**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Travis W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to handle what I was looking for:
(Important note, I was being thrown off by Typescript type-mismatch errors, but they were not preventing compile).

```
  ngOnInit() {

    let amiiboRequest = this.amiiboService.getAllAmiibo();
    let collectionRequest = this.amiiboService.getCollection(this.userId);

    forkJoin([amiiboRequest, collectionRequest]).subscribe(results => {
      const amiiboResponse = results[0];
      const collectionResponse = results[1];

      this.amiiboCollection = [];

      let collected;
      amiiboResponse.forEach((amiibo) => {
        collectionResponse.forEach((collection) => {
          if (amiibo.amiiboId == collection.amiiboId) {
            collected = true;
            this.amiiboCollection.push({...amiibo, ...collection, collected});
          }
        });

        if (!collected) {
          this.amiiboCollection.push({...amiibo, collected});
        }

        collected = false;
      });

      console.log(this.amiiboCollection);
    });
  }
```

Definitely a cleaner way, I will update this at a later time with that once I figure it out.

**UPDATE:**
The "cleaner way" for me, was changing the backend to handle a lot of the heavy lifting. I set my model up to include Collection (as an Object) which in this case resulted in only needing the following on the front end:

```
amiiboCollection = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.amiiboService.getAllAmiibo()
    .subscribe( results => {
      this.amiiboCollection = results;
    });
  }
```

This isn't always going to be the answer, but in this case I felt it worked the best. The original solution is still above for anyone who doesn't have the option I had to make changes to their backend.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, when you add attribute on object the javascript create this if not exist than the code like this:

```
const requests = request1;
requests.collections = request2;
```

the attribute collections of object requests is an array of collection